# Regex to extract bundle ID on ios

Tags: regex

I am trying to extract bundle id from ios using the following regex:

```
^\w+(\.\w+)+
```

It works for most of the cases but fails on others.

eg using below package names:

```
com.walmartmexico.WalmartMG
com.adobe.Adobe-Reader
com.instacart
gnustos.my.app.com.foo89.app.my.long.package.name.is.very.long
org.freevpn.vpn
com.adobe.scan.ios
com.adobe.Adobe-Reader
fontskeyboard.fonts
co.9count.wink
biser.stories
com.ephedra-software.StackOv
de.barbaraherold.freiheit
```

It doesnot capture fully the ones which have hypens:

```
com.ephedra-software.StackOv
com.adobe.Adobe-Reader
```

Any ideas how can I change my above regex to include the above as well.

Comment: Add hyphan to the character set? [`^\w+(\.[\w-]+)+`](https://regex101.com/r/6WEGX6/1/)

Comment: Extract from longer text or validate? For validation, the posted solution works. For extracting, you need `\b\w+(?:[.-]\w+)*\b`

Comment: I am extracting it from user agents eg: com.adobe.Adobe-Reader/16.05.9 (iPad8,11; U; CPU iOS 14_4 like Mac OS X; en_US)', 'Poshmark/5.02.02 (com.poshmark.poshmark; build:1275; iOS 14.4.0)'. When I tried above regex it gives me it as list:

[com.adobe.Adobe-Reader, 16.05.9, iPad8, 11, U, CPU, iOS, 14_4, like, Mac, OS, X, en_US]
[Poshmark, 5.02.02, com.poshmark.poshmark, build, 1275, iOS, 14.4.0]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use:

```regex
^\w+(?:[.-]\w+)*$
```

### Demo

Explanation:

```regex
^                from the start of the input
    \w+          match one or more word characters
    (?:          followed by
        [.-]     dot or hyphen separator
        \w+      one or more word characters
    )*           subsequent terms zero or more times
$                end of the input
```